# How to write a WPF user control in F#?

Tags: wpf, f#, user-controls

Can a WPF user control be written in F#?

Lets say I have a standard WPF/C# user control as:

```
public class DataGridAnnotationControl : UserControl
    {
        static DataGridAnnotationControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DataGridAnnotationControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DataGridAnnotationControl)));
        }
        
        public DataGridAnnotationControl()
        {
            BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
            Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(20, 20, 20, 20);
        }
        
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LastNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LastNameProperty, value); }
        }
        
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LastNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LastName", typeof(string), typeof(DataGridAnnotationControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
        
}
```

How is this coded in F#?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, creating the user control in F# (without a library) will typically be quite different than in C#.

The main issue is you can't use partial classes, so the designer will not function. Even if you ditch the designer, the typical workflow with XAML files does not work properly. To do this in "pure" F#, you typically need to write the UI in code vs doing it in XAML and allowing the generated `InitializeComponent()` method to wire things together.

However, one way to get there in a more "natural" method is to use [FsXaml](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml). It allows you to write user controls directly which become usable in a similar way to C# developed ones. This is done via a [type provider and overriding the default information](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml/blob/master/demos/WpfSimpleMvvmApplication/MainView.xaml.fs#L11-L20).

Comment: The example in the question doesn't look like a UserControl with an associated XAML file. There is no constructor with an InitializeComponent call and no partial declaration, but a default Style key assignment instead. Looks more like a "custom control".

Comment: @Clemens  Correct...my main problem however is how to write a dependency property and refer to a style held in generic.xaml.  To be more precise, this code actually will be used to write an adorner holding a control defined with xaml.

Comment: @ReedCopsey  I'm new to F#. I don't suppose you could share a template or example of how to make a custom or user control with FsXaml?  Thanks.